# Does the movement reduction penalty  from Chilled and Crippled stack?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The conditions [Chilled](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Chilled) and [Crippled](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crippled) both reduce the movement speed of the target (by 66% and 50% respectively). Does the movement speed reduction for each skill apply, or does the movement speed from only one of the conditions apply? In other words, if a target is inflicted with both **Chilled** *and* **Crippled**, what will be their total reduced movement speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the links you provide say "Stacks in duration". According to the [Effect Stacking](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Effect_stacking) page

> Effects stack in one of two ways: in intensity or in duration. For
>   example, multiple stacks of bleeding, which stacks in intensity,
>   increase the damage dealt over time, and multiple stacks of
>   regeneration, which stacks in duration, increase the duration that the
>   healing over time lasts.

It also says

> The best intensity lasts for the cumulative duration

Originally I interpreted this to say higher damage trumps lesser damage but increases duration which is incorrect. Based on info I found at [Guild Wars Insider](http://www.guildwarsinsider.com/beliastas-effect-stacking-breakdown/) the answer becomes a little more complicated.

Multiple duration effects are applied in sequence for their applicable lengths of time. In this example lets say Chilled got applied then Crippled within 10 seconds of each other and both effects are for 60 seconds in length. Chilled would get applied to you for 66% reduction, Crippled would wait until Chilled had finished then immediately get applied to you for the 50% reduction for another 60 seconds.

The blog post at [Guild Wars Insider](http://www.guildwarsinsider.com/beliastas-effect-stacking-breakdown/) has a nice graphic to show how this stacking occurs if my explanation is confusing.

Comment: That applies to stacking the same skill. For example, if I stack both poison and burn, both conditions will inflict damage, not just one of them.

Comment: Gotcha. I dug a little deeper and found a blog post that explains the concept correctly which I tested online tonight. I edited my answer to reflect the new information.